# Handling model inheritance within Rails controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm building a Rails 4 app and using the 'acts_as_relation' gem to model structure that looks like:

```
Item
|
|
---------------------
|                   |
|                   |
Article             Photo
```

This all works fine on a model level but when it comes to controllers, I have defined:

```
resources :articles
resources :photos
resources :items
```

I'd like to the user to be able to use a url like "/items/5" to access the 5th item in the DB but naturally it needs to be able to use the correct view (either article or photo).

In my controller I can easily detect the specific class of an Item but in order to use it's views I **think** I need to do a redirect. This results in a HTTP response code of 302 but I want a nice 200.

I know I can superclass controllers but not sure how this will help as I still need the "superclass controller" to define the type.

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: As per my understanding you can create 2 views in views/items/ and name would be photo.html.erb and artical.html.erb
and in you def show {
  @item = Item.find(params[:id])
end May be it helps you.

 rednder "items/#{@item.specific}"}

Comment: @Neelesh Doesn't work I'm afraid - the def show method still looks for show.html.erb by default.

Comment: if possible please show us show method code

Comment: The show method? I copied what you submitted: def show { @item = Item.find(params[:id]) end